# What does realm divide do in Shogun 2

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

What are all the effects and how long does it last? Can the effects be influenced in anyway?

Answer (score 6):

When you achieve enough fame, the shogun considers you a threat and orders all other clans to declare war. This includes allies who you may have had since the start of the game.

The mechanism by which this work is that all your relationships are set at -40 and continue to decrease as turns pass. Now, any new vassels you create will not be affected by this penalty (nor will their relationships).

Comment: So it's less "realm divided" as "realm solidly and permanently united *against you*"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't exactly fit with what i've seen so far. I've just had it happen to me, that's why i'm asking. On Medium, i get a -20 relation penalty with, and not all the other clans have declared war on me yet. Good to know i can get rid of the relation penalty though.

Comment: @Bubble the penalty is based on difficulty level.  Also, its a growing penalty so it doesn't guarantee war.

Comment: I have experienced that on Legendary difficulty, newly created vassals after the Realm Divide, still get the Realm Divide penalty. I thought first time it was an aberration, but happened to my second legendary campaign too. It seems to be unique to Legendary. I did not see this at very hard level (or I don't remember that I did).